# Python 2.7: Calling a text file from various locations

Tags: python

So, I'm in the windows environment.

1. I created the text file with notepad.
2. I saved it in my documents.
3. I opened python's idle shell.
4. I used `testFile = open("test.txt","a+")`
5. Typed `testFile.read()`

Hit enter and the result was '' two single quotes?

Comment: open in read mode with 'r'

Comment: ... or ignore the flag altogether, as `'r'` is the default opening flag

Comment: @inspectorG4dget:  A file opened with mode `a+` will still return results when read.  My guess is that he is specifying the incorrect path to the file.  Or specifying no path so that it's trying to open the file from the current directory, not "My Documents".

Comment: Fair point @StevenRumbalski. I don't usually use `a+`, so that slipped my mind

Comment: On Windows in Idle `os.getcwd()` returns `'C:\\Python27'` (unless you installed Python elsewhere).  That is where Python is trying to find your file.  If you want it to look in "My Documents" you need to provide the path.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the full path to your text file if it is not in your current working directory:

```
testFile = open("c:/Users/yourusername/My Documents/text.txt")
```

Answer (score -4):

```
testFile = open("test.txt", "rb")
testFile.read()
```

Comment: javascript  <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: Why does javascript print c:/user/ma/ etc  together with what it is supposed to print?